# Laravel Homestead is slow on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, homestead

On my work machine (with the same configuration) its works fine. But on a home laptop is very slow. I tried to destroy it and then to `up`, but no effect.
This is my config:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox
ssl: true

folders:
    - map: ~/pr/my-site.loc
      to: /home/vagrant/my-site.loc

sites:
    - map: my-site.loc
      to: /home/vagrant/my-site.loc/public
      type: apache
      php: "7.4"

databases:
    - my_site_loc
```

When I run `vagrant up` I get several warnings:

[image: Screenshot]

P. S. Maybe a memory leak ...

P. S. 2 Opened UI VirtualBox. Fixed the errors that he highlighted:

- Graphics Controller set to VMSVGA
- Added graphics memory just in case
- Installed Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.18.vbox-extpack

[image: VirtualBox Settings]

Got better. At least it doesn't turn off ...

Comment: You're not asking a question and this also seems to be about the use of some software, not about programming.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I understood you. Sorry. I don't have much experience on StackOverflow yet.

Answer (score 1):

Most Probably the slowness is due to the "share folder"

Try to use the NFS.

```
folders:
    - map: ~/code/project1
      to: /home/vagrant/project1
      type: "nfs"
```

In short you can refer the Laravel Documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#configuring-shared-folders

In detail walkthrough, you can refer this tutorial
https://dogcomp.medium.com/install-laravel-8-x-on-win-10-with-homestead-virtualbox-ec996f9a2cb6